# FirePHP beginner issues

Tags: php, ubuntu, firephp

I am writing a web page that uses some php files.   The php isn't working properly and I am trying to debug for things such as printing variables.  I am new to php so this is all new territory.

I use firebug for other debugging and css alignment so I thought firephp might be a good way to begin.

I added firePHP into firefox and then following some tutorials I found I added this to my php file:

```
<?PHP
/* comment here down to line 15 */
require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.PHP');
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
```

The result I get when I load my page is:

`Warning: require_once(FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.PHP): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/contactform.php on line 15 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.PHP' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/contactform.php on line 15`

It seems like some more setup and library loading is required, but I am not sure what or how?

I am developing on Ubuntu using apache and /var/www/ as my local server.

```
Description:        Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty
```

Advice on how to get past this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the "FirePHPCore" folder to the same directory that this code is being run in

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  I downloaded FirePHPCore and put it in `/var/www/`, `/var/www/include/`, and `/usr/share/php`.  I get the same same results. `/usr/share/php/` is listed as an include directory.   Any other advice?

Comment: I also tried: `sudo apt-get install php-pear`; 
`sudo pear channel-discover pear.firephp.org`;
`sudo pear install firephp/FirePHPCore`;  also to no avail.  Same error message...  what gives??

Comment: That error is thrown when the file trying be loaded via "require" doesn't exist. Here are the instructions for installing the server code: http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Install.htm

Comment: you have to point your `require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.PHP');` to the directory that FirePHP is installed in. http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Learn.htm

Comment: Thanks!  That was the clue I needed.  (Modified the question show the include path.)  pear installed FirePHPCore in `/usr/share/php`  I also restarted apache2 which I hadn't previously and my error went away.

Comment: I assumed incorrectly that my app root = www. doh! so this failed "require_once ('/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');" I had to reference like this "require_once ('../FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');" (Note the ../). Hope that helps someone. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');

The file extension (.php) is NOT SUPPOSED TO BE CAPITALIZED.